# Tracking music/mp3 file plays?

Tags: mp3

I'm working on a service that generates mp3 music files for user's to download. Once the music is generated, its theirs to keep and use but it would be nice to be able to build anonymous stats on how often the music file is played.

Is there any mechanism by which I could do this? Would any of the mp3 ID tag be of use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible, there is nothing that would force a mp3 player to report the playback.

Comment: would any other audio formats allow for behaviour (if the player supported it)?

Comment: Hard to say. Formats like FLAC or OGG allow user defined tags which a player could use - but I don't know of any player that actually support this.

Comment: @user783836 there is not way, unfortunately, to do so. What you can do, is to create some kind of your own format, and people should download an your reader that can read that format. The reader, wil send the metadata to you each time the file is played, together with an unique ID that identifies the player, so that you will have stats for each player how many times that song was player.

Comment: @greg-449 tags are only text metadata. There is not any way to include any script/executable that can perform any action